# gsed replace by a variable $i with single quote

Tags: bash, variables, sed, environment-variables, zsh

I have into a text file the following line :

```
\[Omega]BD=100;
```

I would like to replace with gsed the value `100` by a shell variable (zsh shell), here `600` :

I tried :

```
$ i=600

$ gsed  's/\[Omega]BD=.*/\[Omega]BD=\'\\"$i"\\';/' text_to_modify.txt | grep 600
```

but it returns me :

`\[Omega]BD=\600;` and not `\[Omega]BD=600;`

The is an additional backslash that I don't want, I wonder how could I remove this backslash. I would like to keep the two single quotes of `gsed 's/.../.../'`

Comment: `gsed`??? Are you on MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`;

```
i=600
$ sed "/\[Omega]/s/[[:digit:]]\+/$i/" input_file
\[Omega]BD=600;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed` command:

```bash
i=600
sed -E "s/(\\\\\[Omega]BD=).*/\1$i;/" file

\[Omega]BD=600;
```

We require additional escaping i.e. `\\\\` to match a single `\` because we are using double quotes around full sed command.

Or we can avoid you can use this combination of single and double quotes to avoid extra escaping:

```
sed -E 's/(\\\[Omega]BD=).*/\1'"$i;/" file
```